# How to select a particular version of an r package?

Tags: r

I want to run package "multcomp", it requires a dependant package "survival",

but I have two versions of survival stored in two different locations.

```
survival "/panfs/panasas01/socs/yy5245/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2"
survival "/cm/shared/languages/R-3.2.2-ATLAS/lib64/R/library"

survival "2.41-3" "recommended" "R (>= 2.13.0)"
survival "2.38-3" "recommended" "R (>= 2.13.0), graphics, stats"
```

multcomp seems to only recognise the 2.38-3 version which is too old. How to make multcomp only choose 2.41-3 version?

Thanks

so, I have tried

```
.libPaths()

[1] "/panfs/panasas01/socs/yy5245/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2"
[2] "/cm/shared/languages/R-3.2.2-ATLAS/lib64/R/library"

search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"            "package:MASS"          "package:survival"
 [4] "package:BiocInstaller" "package:stats"         "package:graphics"
 [7] "package:grDevices"     "package:utils"         "package:datasets"
[10] "package:methods"       "Autoloads"             "package:base"
> detach(3,unload=TRUE)
```

re-load survival in the defined path

```
library("survival",lib.loc="/panfs/panasas01/socs/yy5245/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
```

but when I install from github, I still get

```
install_github("perishky/meffil",lib=.libPaths()[1])
Downloading GitHub repo perishky/meffil@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/perishky/meffil/zipball/master
Installing meffil
'/cm/shared/languages/R-3.2.2-ATLAS/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-site-file  \
  --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpCRXJSM/devtools5252a46ada7/perishky-meffil-e385e64'  \
  --library='/panfs/panasas01/socs/yy5245/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2'  \
  --install-tests

 installing *source* package 'meffil' ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: character(0)
Error : package 'survival' 2.38.3 was found, but >= 2.39.4 is required by 'multcomp'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'meffil'
* removing '/panfs/panasas01/socs/yy5245/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/meffil'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

What I don't understand is, when I check the survival, it is the correct version being loaded...

```
packageVersion("survival")
[1] '2.41.3'
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd just delete the old one.

Comment: thanks! but I couldn't delete the old one because I am running R from a server and I don't have permission to delete it!

Comment: Fair enough. If you're loading survival directly, you can specify the `lib.loc` parameter of `library`. If not, you can edit `.libPaths()`, which is where it searches if you don't specify.

Comment: Hi, I am very confused. I have tried to unload all the previous loaded survival packages and re-load them again giving the specified lib.loc, but still it didn't work

Comment: You could try editing `.libPaths`, e.g. to reverse it `.libPaths(rev(.libPaths()))`. If that's not sufficient, temporarily take the offending directory off entirely.

Comment: Thank you! Yesterday I have figured out, that I could use `assign(".lib.loc", "\your\preferred\library", envir = environment(.libPaths))` to assign the desired path. So I have solved my problem but thank you very much for helping me!